# How to find smallest or biggest index in Stack

Tags: java, sorting, search

How to find smallest or biggest index in Stack  without using the array and how to sort them. Only use peek(), push() and pop() method in stack .

Comment: Sorry I mean the biggest or smallest value in the arraystack

Answer (score -1):

For index retrieve, you may use `size()` method to get the largest index.

The methods you mentioned are for value retrieve.

Comment: @TedLaw If you want to implement the Stack API yourself, you can maintain a method `size()`, and if you implement the Stack using an array, `size()` simply returns this array's length. If you want to use Java's Stack API, there seems no `size()` method provided. But you can use `peek()` to get the top item and then `search()`, the int number returned is the size.

Comment: opps, I just notice I asked the wrong question. I meant find the biggest value in the Arraystack.

Comment: Then it depends on the object in your stack and the rule of your compare. At least you should implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` Interface in your object.